# Using 'disaggregate' with GCM data

Tags: r, raster

I have data from various Global Circulation Models (GCM) that I need in at a finer resolution to perturb climate observations that are 0.5 degree pixel. I saw that I could use disaggregate because this function won't change pixels values, as 'resample' does using, e.g., the bilinear method. But still, the output doesn't match my fine-res-grids.

Here an example with the dimensions of the files I'm dealing with:

```
r = raster(ncols=720, nrows=360) #fine resolution grid
r[] = runif(1:100)
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 360, 720, 259200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0.0159161, 0.9876637  (min, max)

s = raster(ncols=192, nrows=145) #dimensions of one of the GCM
s[] = runif(1:10)
> s
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 145, 192, 27840  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1.875, 1.241379  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0.03861309, 0.9744665  (min, max)


d=disaggregate(s, fact=c(3.75,2.482759)) #fact equals r/s for cols and rows
> d
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 290, 768, 222720  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.46875, 0.6206897  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0.03861309, 0.9744665  (min, max)
```

The dimensions of 'd' are not equal to the dimensions of 'r', so I can't do operations with the 2 grids. And I'm not meant to be interpolating the pixel values. So, what's the best method to achieve the disaggregation with GCM data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From `?disaggregate`, `fact` is a single integer or two integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should help- it uses aggregate to the closest integer scaling possible then resample to match the other raster's spatial characteristics exactly:

```
r = raster(ncols=720, nrows=360) #fine resolution grid
r[] = runif(1:100)

s = raster(ncols=192, nrows=145) #dimensions of one of the GCM
s[] = runif(1:10)

d=disaggregate(s, fact=c(round(dim(r)[1]/dim(s)[1]),round(dim(r)[2]/dim(s)[2])), method='') #fact equals r/s for cols and rows
e=resample(d, r,  method="ngb")
```

But there a few caveats/ warnings: If you want to have the same values as the original raster, use disaggregate with method='' or else it will interpolate. But most important looking at the aspect ratio between your r and s rasters, they are not the same: dim(r)[1]/dim(s)[1] != dim(r)[2]/dim(s)[2]). I would double check the original data because if there is a difference in resolution, projection, or extent you will not get what you want from the steps above.

Comment: Thanks @LucasFortini, it seems to work. But I need to check final pixel values.

Comment: I agree with you approach, though I prefer the following for calculating `fact`: `round(res(r) / res(s))`